# Will Erlang have Bignums for math functions?

Tags: erlang, bignum

Why does Erlang not include arbitrary precision for math functions? I recently had to use `math:pow(2,4333)`, and it throws an error. Why does Erlang not use libraries like GMP? Are there any plans to include it in the standard library? (Haskell uses it, [strike]even Java has bignums[strike]).

Thanks.

Update:
To add more perspective, I understand that it can be done using NIFs. I was solving problems from hackerrank in which the input uses larger numbers. pow/2 can be easily written in Erlang and it worked, but for larger computations, it would be slow.
Java returns double for `pow` so it does not work for `Math.pow(2, 1024)` which gives `Infinity`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Erlang has bignums for integers but uses 64-bit IEEE standard floating point numbers. So while you can happily compute `factorial(10000)` with integers by default the `math` library uses floating point so `math:pow(2, 4333)` does not work.

Comment: `crypto` module uses integers and defines `crypto:mod_pow/3` which you can use instead of `math:pow/2` if it fits your needs.

Comment: this answer doesn't answer the question, like at all.

Comment: Because it wasn't deemed interesting for most uses of Erlang. If you want to do serious numerical calculation you would call a suitable package from Erlang.