# Erlang; math.pow, why not integer by default or typed for floats/ints?

Tags: erlang

I thought Erlang handled arbitrary precision Integers. But it looks like math.pow uses floats by default:

Using the linux utility `bc`:

```
88^99
31899548991064687385194313314353745484864573065650712770111884048604\
75359372836550565046276541670202826515718633320519821593616663471686\
151960018780508843851702573924250277584030257178740785152
```

Removing backslashes:

```
3189954899106468738519431331435374548486457306565071277011188404860475359372836550565046276541670202826515718633320519821593616663471686151960018780508843851702573924250277584030257178740785152
```

In Erlang:

```
float_to_list(math:pow(88,99),[{scientific,192}]).
"3.189954899106468677983468001676918389478607432406058411199358053788184470654582587122118156926366989707830958889227847846886750593566290713618113587727930256898153980172821794148406939795587072e+192"
```

Side by side:

```
bc:  3189954899106468738519431331435374548486457306565071277011188404860475359372836550565046276541670202826515718633320519821593616663471686151960018780508843851702573924250277584030257178740785152
erl: 3189954899106468677983468001676918389478607432406058411199358053788184470654582587122118156926366989707830958889227847846886750593566290713618113587727930256898153980172821794148406939795587072
```

I wrote a naive function:

```
integerpow(N, 1) -> N;
integerpow(N, M) -> N*integerpow(N, M-1).
```

which produces the correct answer.

But it seems the default behavior when both arguments are in integers should produce the correct answer, *why doesn't it*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `math` module just wraps what's in the C library.  As [the manual page](http://erlang.org/doc/man/math.html) says:

> ## Bugs
>
> As these are the C library, the bugs are the same.

(though you might question whether returning a floating point number instead of a bignum is a "bug")

That's also what the type signature for `pow` says:

```
pow(X, Y) -> float()

    Y = X = number()
```

That is, the function is specified to accept any number, i.e. both integers and floats, but always return a float.

---

Why is that, then?

I couldn't find any authoritative answer as to whether a contribution adding a bignum exponentiation function to the standard library would be accepted, so give it a try and submit a pull request!  (Or perhaps [an EEP](http://www.erlang.org/erlang-enhancement-proposals/).)

Though I did find [an alternative implementation](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2012-March/065268.html) (returning a value of the same type as the base argument) on the erlang-questions mailing list, and [a Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19893708/113848) on a similar topic, and a [mailing list thread](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2003-May/008839.html) discussing how to use very big numbers, bigger than feasible even for bignums.

Answer (score 0):

Erlang, and for that matter any library, or even simple calculators, don't calculate large integer powers by naively multiplying numbers multiple times. They use a specific mathematical formula called [Exponentiation_by_squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). It calculates the powers through polynomial approximation. The approximation is exact for small numbers but gets less and less accurate for bigger numbers and it of course depends on the precision implemented in the underlying library. The [math library in Erlang](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/math.erl) is a NIF-like proxy to the [underlying C implementation](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/erts/emulator/beam/erl_math.c).

**Edit:**

This seems to be a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893708/will-erlang-have-bignums-for-math-functions).

There is also a question on math.stackexchange.com that cites the same source for the [computation algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176252/how-to-handle-big-powers-on-big-numbers-e-g-n915937897123891).

So, you already answered your question in the question itself. Erlang handles arbitrary precision integers but the module `math` does not, it uses `float` by default.

Comment: This answer basically says "the answer is wrong because they feel like making it efficient instead of correct".

Comment: Yeah, that's how `math` is implemented. It uses floats to calculate powers and returns approximate results, like all libraries using floats. Erlang VM itself handles big integers but it doesn't mean that all OTP libraries do the same. I added an edit to my response with more links.